# custom button on uinavigationbar not respnding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Ive working on an ios app and i am currently trying to add custom buttons to my navbar.

```
UIBarButtonItem *optButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                       initWithTitle:@"Option1"                                            
                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                       target:self 
                                       action:@selector(Option:)];

        UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:title];
        item.leftBarButtonItem = optButton;

        [navBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:YES];
        [optButton release];
        [item release];



-(void)Option:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"****Look at me!*****");


}
```

Now this works in that it displays the button on my navbar on the left as hoped but nothing happens when i click on the button. it doesnt react to touch at all. How do i get the custom button to react to user input? the navbar is created in code and im not using a nav controller or IB at all. I have the navbars delegate set with

```
[ navBar setDelegate: self ];
```

within the view controller that owns it. any help would be appreciated

edit: this is how i create the navbar in viewdidload

```
navBar = [ [ UINavigationBar alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45.0f)];
    [ navBar setDelegate: self ];
    [navBar pushNavigationItem:[ [ UINavigationItem alloc ] initWithTitle:@"MoM" ] animated:YES];

    [ self.view addSubview: navBar ];
```

the reason for not using a nav controller for this is that i want to be able to change properties of the navbar and according to apples references on nav controllers i shouldnt amend the frame of a nav controllers nav bar directly. If im misunderstanding this please say so. I dont need a nav controller in this view controller as it will be displayed at all times in the app. I have separate nav controllers that handle transition of other view controllers separately but this particular view controller is a stand alone entity that is always available at top of the screen no matter what is going on else where

> Discussion
>
> It is permissible to modify the barStyle or translucent properties of
>   the navigation bar but you must never change its frame, bounds, or
>   alpha values directly. To show or hide the navigation bar, you should
>   always do so through the navigation controller by changing its
>   navigationBarHidden property or calling the
>   setNavigationBarHidden:animated: method.

edit2:

after some more research i see people have had their apps rejected from messing with the navbar frame properties within a nav controller so im def not gonna try this. I see on apples site that they do allow a stand alone navbar which i can mess with its properties and have the view controller take the uinavbar delegate. making the view controller have to handle all the input through the navbar directly. this looks to be the approach i want

> If you are using a navigation bar as a standalone object, you should
>   assign a custom delegate object to the delegate property and use that
>   object to intercept messages coming from the navigation bar. Delegate
>   objects must conform to the UINavigationBarDelegate protocol. The
>   delegate notifications let you track when navigation items are pushed
>   or popped from the stack. You would use these notifications to update
>   the rest of your application’s user interface.

Comment: Why do you create the navBar as a subview of your current view? Why didn't you use a navigation controller?

Comment: i want to animate the navbars location depending on different events that happen within that viewcontroller.

Comment: I believe you can still do the same if you create a nav bar using the navigation controller and add this view controller as the navigation controller's root view controller. See Prakash's comment on his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the current view controller's `navigationItem`'s `leftBarButtonItem` property instead of creating one and pushing..

```
UIBarButtonItem *optButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                           initWithTitle:@"Option1"                                            
                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                           target:self 
                                           action:@selector(Option:)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [optButton autorelease];
```

Comment: this doesnt display the button on my navbar. i added how im creating the navbar in above question. maybe that will show what im doing wrong

Comment: How do you create the UIViewcontroller in question?

Comment: StatusPanelViewController *statusPanel = [[StatusPanelViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:statusPanel.view]; in the appdelegate

Comment: Add UINavigationController object in your app delegate. And create it like  navCtrlr = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:statusPanel]; Now you can add Navigationcontrollers view property to window instead.  [self.window addSubview:navCtrlr.view];

Comment: thanks for the help. you are correct in that this solves my problem of buttons not responding but i found a new problem of not being allowed to amend the frame in code by apple. back to the drawing board with this i think. thanks again good to know for future anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar, only I do it like:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    self.navigationItem.title = @"My Title";
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = 
        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save"
                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                        target:self 
                                        action:@selector(save)];
    ...
}

- (void) save
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: yeah i tried it that way too but i dont think (and could clearly be very wrong) it works when u have created your own navbar in code with no nav controller. it just doesnt display anything this way for me. Do you have a nav controller?

Comment: Yes I do have a UINavigationController setup.  Note that I created the UINavigationController in code.  Is there a reason you aren't using a UINavigationController?

Comment: maybe im misunderstanding the nav controller then. i thought it was just needed to actually navigate and push and pop views onto it. i dont require this from my navbar and i need to be able to animate its location. I have separate navcontrollers set up in code to handle the actual transitions of views but for this particular view controller i want it to be in view at all times and be able animate and use the nav bar independently of any other view controllers that are displayed behind it. the view controller in question with the navbar only take up a portion of the screen.

Comment: im gonna try adding in a nav controller for it anyway to see if it allows me to access my custom button functionality

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the `optButton` being added anywhere to the navigation item. What I see is this line:

```
item.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Perhaps you need to change the `backButton` to `optButton`? (unless its not just a typo in the question).

Comment: Since you have posted only a partial code snippet (and because this is the only potential problem that I can see), are you sure that the method defining `optButton` (assuming its an instance method) and `-Option:` are declared for the same class? (i.e. is `self` the same for both of these methods?)

I am sorry if this sounds like a stupid question to ask.

Comment: yeah optbutton is defined in viewdidload and option: is within the same class. ask as many questions as you want/can ! ive been stumped on this for hours and its driving me mad. Im sure im missing something stupid and obvious but i cant for the life of me see it.